# Android - getCurrentUser() returns null when opening an activity from notification

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I've an app where if a user is signed in, he will receive notifications. When he clicks on the notifications he will be redirected to a HomeActivity. I have a class that runs whenever the app is opened, to check if a user is signed in or not. If he is signed in he will be directed to HomeActivity or else RestaurantAuthActivity.
The issue is when I sign in the user and click on the notification received, it is redirecting me that specific activity, but when I close the app and try to start it again, it redirects me to RestaurantAuthActivity. On checking, I see that when I'm directed to HomeActivity form the notification, the getCurrentUser() returns null, which should not be null.
I've a separate "Sign Out" button in HomeActivity which signs out the user.
Home.class checks if a user is signed in or not whenever the app is started

```
public class Home extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("RestaurantInfo", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String restaurantID = sharedPreferences.getString("RestaurantID", "");

        if (firebaseUser != null) {

            System.out.println("FirebaseUSER: " + firebaseUser);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);

        } else {
            System.out.println("FirebaseUSER inside false: " + firebaseUser);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RestaurantAuthActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

}
```

As per XML, the RestaurantAuthActivity is my launcher activity. The reason why it is still directing me to HomeActivity is because of the below code snippet in RestaurantAuthActivity.

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra("page")) {

        System.out.println("Inside getIntent()");
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Could someone help me on this!

Comment: where's the notfication?

Comment: Use an auth state listener to find out when the Firebase Auth recognizes the user as fully signed in.  It's not guaranteed to be available immediately on launch.

Comment: @DougStevenson whenever I open the app normally i.e, not through notification.. the Home.class works.. then any reason why it is not working in this situation?

Comment: As I said, you don't have a guarantee that the current user is available immediately on a cold launch. A listener will tell you exactly when that data is available.

Comment: @DougStevenson okay... i get it now.. so should I set the auth state listener in Home.class or RestaurantAuthActivity.class.. I tried setting up the auth state listener in Home.class, but it is not working.. if I sign in and close the app and try to run it again it is directing me to my launcher activity instead of HomeActivity

Comment: Sounds like you should ask a new question and provide that code that isn't working the way you expect.